# Can Mean be smaller than SD if the scores have negative numbers

Tags: variance

Many of the articles discuss about the relationship between mean and standard deviation of numbers above zero stating that mean should be greater than standard deviation

But if the numbers or the data has negative integers with scores ranging from -10 to +10, is it necessary that mean should be greater than standard deviation.

Comment: many of *which* articles?

Comment: I suspect this is a sort of poor-man's Normality test: the the data are all positive and the standard deviation is larger than the mean then the data obviously are not close to Normal.

Comment: Even after checking for normality the mean is less than SD.i mentioned that the raw scores range from -10 to +10.

Comment: in this website also there is one query about the relationship between mean and SD and it is mentioned that mean is expected to be greater than SD

Answer (score 2):

The mean can be smaller than the standard deviation in your example, and even when all of the numbers in the dataset are positive.  For example, the set {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100} has a mean of just over 15, but the SD is about 37.4.

In the case where all of the numbers are negative, the mean will certainly be smaller than the SD, since the SD will always be >= 0 (since it's the square root of the variance), and the mean always negative.

In short, the relationship between the mean and the standard deviation depends on the specific dataset--there's no requirement that the mean be larger than the SD.

Comment: But in the example of {1,1,1,1,1,1,100} the data is not normally distributed if it is normally distributed??